# Does the location of a lambda expression matter in Lazy Initialization?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried the Lazy Initialization [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN. And I tried to mimic the static InitLargeObject() method with a static Func< T > delegate using a lambda expression since it's acceptable by the Lazy< T > constructor.

```
static Lazy<LargeObject> lazyLargeObject = new Lazy<LargeObject>(InitWithLambda);

static Func<LargeObject> InitWithLambda = () =>
{
    LargeObject large = new LargeObject(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    // Perform additional initialization here. 
    return large;
};


static LargeObject InitLargeObject()
{
    LargeObject large = new LargeObject(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    // Perform additional initialization here. 
    return large;
}

static void Main()
{

    //lazyLargeObject = new Lazy<LargeObject>(InitLargeObject); // <---- This one use the static method.
    lazyLargeObject = new Lazy<LargeObject>(InitWithLambda); // <---- Thsi one uses the lambda expression.


    Console.WriteLine(
        "\r\nLargeObject is not created until you access the Value property of the lazy" +
        "\r\ninitializer. Press Enter to create LargeObject.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    // Create and start 3 threads, each of which uses LargeObject.
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        threads[i] = new Thread(ThreadProc);
        threads[i].Start();
    }

    // Wait for all 3 threads to finish.  
    foreach (Thread t in threads)
    {
        t.Join();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress Enter to end the program");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If I put the **InitWithLambda** delegate **before** the **lazyLargeObject** declaration, everything is fine.

If I put the **InitWithLambda** delegate **after** the **lazyLargeObject** declaration, I got this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'Program' threw an  exception. --->
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   valueFactory    at System.Lazy`1..ctor(Func`1 valueFactory,
>   LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)    at System.Lazy`1..ctor(Func`1
>   valueFactory)    at Program..cctor() in
>   E:\myCode\Misc\LazyWithLambda\LazyWithLambda\Class1.cs:line 10    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Program.Main()

It seems the lambda expression failed to be assinged to the valueFactory parameter.

But it seems the location doesn't affect the **InitLargeObject() method**, which is not using Lambda expression.

Why?

### Update 1

According to [Billy ONeal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587523/does-the-location-of-a-lambda-expression-matter-in-lazy-initialization/24587584#24587584), I reproed this issue with a simpler code:

This one is ok:

```
class FieldInitInOrder
{        
    static string s1 = "abc";
    static Int32 s1_length = s1.Length;

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s1_length);
    }
}
```

This one throw the same NullReference exception:

```
class FieldInitInOrder
{
    static Int32 s1_length = s1.Length;  // Order switched
    static string s1 = "abc";  // Order switched

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s1_length);
    }
}
```

I don't know why C# compiler is designed like this. It could cause very delicate bugs.
Is there any design consideration?

Comment: It is not possible in general to make the compiler ensure a safe ordering. You could say `static bool dummy = DoAnything(ref s1_length, ref s1);`. The compiler cannot ensure safety here.

Comment: Regarding your follow-up question: It is simply not a good idea to field initializers depend on the order of initialization, at all. If you need to follow a logical order, use a constructor. It is impossible for the compiler to guess the correct order in each and every situation. As you mentioned, this can very easily lead to bugs if another programmer decides to do some refactoring, or something that would normally have no effect.

Answer (score 6):

C# initializes members in the order in which they are declared.

Comment: Upvoted. "Members" here are just `static` fields that have field initializers. The static field initializers are run in their _textual_ order. If the class/struct is `partial` and there are static fields in several "parts" of the class such that the fields refer each other, I think the order is unspecified. It is always a good idea, in complex cases, to drop the field initializers and write the assignments in the desired order inside a static constructor.

Comment: Non-static field initializers also run in textual order, but that is only relevant if the instance field initializers have "static" side effects. For instance fields are not allowed to refer each other.

Answer (score 3):

This is by design, according to the C# Specification:

> The textual order in which names are declared is generally of no
> significance. In particular, textual order is not significant for the
> declaration and use of namespaces, constants, methods, properties,
> events, indexers, operators, instance constructors, destructors,
> static constructors, and types. Declaration order is significant in
> the following ways:
>
> • Declaration order for field declarations and local variable
> declarations determines the order in which their initializers (if any)
> are executed.
>
> • Local variables must be defined before they are used
> (§3.7).
>
> •  Declaration order for enum member declarations (§14.3) is
> significant when constant-expression values are omitted.

The values will be initialized in the order they are declared.